# Put the common tags in brackets, instead of using hyphens

Tags: feature-request, title

When I ask a question on Stack Overflow, and I give it the tag [php](/questions/tagged/php), then it automatically puts this in the title:

> php - My question title

I think the tag [php](/questions/tagged/php) should be in brackets (or COLON):

> [php] My question title

or

> php | My question title

Because, at this moment, it causes my title to be read incorrectly. I think users should be able to decide to include the tag in the title or not.

Comment: Making it optional would mean we'd get both forms in the feed: "[php] some question" and "php - some other question". That would just be confusing for readers.

Comment: Meh, does it really matter? ... All I can say is: [bikeshed](https://shed.bike/)

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm afraid many people would find the square brackets to be worse. And making it optional would be too much work spent on too minor request, IMHO.

Comment: Regarding your edit, Google would abbreviate it whether you used "php - " or "[php]". I think you'll need a better example. Perhaps something with multiple hyphens, or where hyphens are part of code. Maybe something like "sql - --; vulnerable to sql injection".

Comment: I still don't like it so my down vote stays but your *I didnt think that i would started to explain grammar basics* made me laugh ...

Comment: @rene that's because comments like "doest it matter?" forced me to explain that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OUH! what a rare occasion, someone didnt directly rejected (nevertheless the fact he disagrees) on a topic I opened on Meta! thank you so much :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually like the idea, but it's not going to happen. It's really a matter of taste, and Stack Overflow chose the "tag - title" format. Changing that now is just a lot of work, for no obvious gain.

I could think of a few cases where "[tag] title" would be preferable, but I could equally well think of cases where "tag - title" would be preferable.

**Example in favor of the proposed change:**

> [sql] -- some sql injection issue

is easier to understand than

> sql - -- some sql injection issue

**Example against the proposed change:**

> tag - some regex or array indexing issue

is easier to understand than

> [tag] some regex or array indexing issue

So, either way there are going to be issues.

Finally, you make a case about how it looks in the Google search results. Comparing "php - is it a good practice" to "[php] is it a good practice".
It's true that the second form makes it more immediately clear that the "good practice" does not refer to PHP itself. However, one should not base decisions on the abbreviated results in a search engine.

Comment: What about `[c#] [0] is invalid here`. Same problem the other way around.

Comment: Wow, someone agrees with a question i opened on META.se ... THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

There might be an UX reason to use tag names consistently, and someone might like brackets over hyphens, or the other way around.

I think there is more to it: SEO. Google likes hyphens as logical separators. I doubt if putting brackets around tag names hurts SEO. It might, and if so, it is a valid reason to use `php` over `[php]`.

Although this is about brand names, I think the general idea in this [Google page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624) still stands:

> In this case, consider including just your site name at the beginning or end of each page title, separated from the rest of the title with a delimiter such as a hyphen, colon, or pipe.